# Unmarshal to custom interface

Tags: json, go

The usual approach for unmarshalling is like this:

```
atmosphereMap := make(map[string]interface{})
err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &atmosphereMap)
```

But how to unmarshal `json` data to custom interface:

```
type CustomInterface interface {
    G() float64
} 

atmosphereMap := make(map[string]CustomInterface)
err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &atmosphereMap)
```

The second way gives me an error:

```
panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.CustomInterface
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: What would you have expected to happen? Or, what would you expect `G()` would do, if the unmarshalling would have been successful?

Comment: @Leon `G()` is just Getter function

Comment: With interfaces defining behaviors and JSON describing data, directly unmarshalling into an interface is impossible. You would at least need a struct, which implements the interface, into which you can then unmarshal. What is the reason you want to do this? There might be a different, simpler approach. Or do you have a set of types, which all implement an interface, where you need to decide while parsing, which one to use?

Comment: @Leon Yes, more close to the second option: I have different types which implements the same interface. I build different trees from json data with help of function that accepts CustomInterface object as argument.
So I want to unmarshal to `CustomInterface` interface then to pass them to function to build tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unmarshal into a set of types, which all implement a common interface, you can implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface on the parent type, the `map[string]CustomInterface` in your case:

```
type CustomInterfaceMap map[string]CustomInterface

func (m CustomInterfaceMap) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    data := make(map[string]json.RawMessage)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &data); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for k, v := range data {
        var dst CustomInterface
        // populate dst with an instance of the actual type you want to unmarshal into
        if _, err := strconv.Atoi(string(v)); err == nil {
            dst = &CustomImplementationInt{} // notice the dereference
        } else {
            dst = &CustomImplementationFloat{}
        }

        if err := json.Unmarshal(v, dst); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        m[k] = dst
    }
    return nil
}
```

For a full example, see [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/p49f8EN9330). Make sure you unmarshal into a `CustomInterfaceMap`, not `map[string]CustomInterface`, otherwise the custom `UnmarshalJSON` method will not be called.

[`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) is a useful type, which is just a raw encoded JSON value, meaning it is a simple `[]byte`, into which the JSON is stored in unparsed form.